# Horizontal multidimensional list

Tags: css, multidimensional-array, html-lists, nested-lists

I have a multidimensional array that is rendered into a HTML list in the same hierarchy:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        First A
        <ul>
            <li>
                Second A (Child of First A)
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Third A (Child of Second A)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Third B (Child of Second A)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Third B (Child of Second A)
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Second B (Child of First A)
            </li>
            <li>
                Second C (Child of First A)
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to display this liste like below without changing the hierarchy … any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some CSS to show what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1):

### There are two options, how you could do it differently to your current solution.

**The first one**: Without JS but with floats so you'll need a `clear: both` at the end of your ULLI construct.
*(I wouldn't use this one because it's partly unstable but I thought I ought post it though)*

[See the Pen](https://codepen.io/moritzgut/pen/MNmNzp)

```html
<style>
div {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

div > ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}

span {
  clear: both;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
<ul>
  <li>
      First A
      <ul>
          <li>
              Second A (Child of First A)
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      Third A (Child of Second A)
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      Third B (Child of Second A)
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      Third B (Child of Second A)
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
              Second B (Child of First A)
          </li>
          <li>
              Second C (Child of First A)
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<span></span>
</div>
```

**Or the second one:**
With a small script that provides the height for the container.

*CSS:*

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 0 250px;
  padding: 0;
}

div > ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

*Javascript:*

```
  let absHeight = 0;
  let uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
  Array.from(uls).forEach(ul => {
    absHeight = (absHeight < ul.offsetHeight) ? ul.offsetHeight : absHeight
  });
  document.getElementById('container').style.height = absHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking but this example can be done with minimum effort with out using position absolute. Do let me know if this help.

Using `display flex` and adding `span`.

```css
li{display: flex;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <span>First A</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Second A (Child of First A)</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Third A (Child of Second A)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Third B (Child of Second A)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Third B (Child of Second A)
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-top:-35px;">
                Second B (Child of First A)
            </li>
            <li>
                Second C (Child of First A)
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i'm using right now and seems to be the best of all solutions i've tried so far … any ideas how to get rid of the gab between 2a and 2b?

Comment: we can do that adding margin-top:-35px; to li of Second B (Child of First A) but not the best solution.